# Updating content to remove it from the front page shows it as being 'New'

Tags: nodes

I am removing content from the front page as it is out dated, but I don't want to un-publish it as it remains valid information.

Unfortunately Drupal then labels the old article as 'New' and put it to the top of the content list, exactly the opposite effect of the one intended.

How can I stop this?

Comment: Consider an extra EDIT of your question related to the "I am removing content from the front page ..." part of it, by explaining HOW you are removing that content (which Drupal function / technique you use for doing so).

Comment: If you have the possibility to develop some code try using `hook_node_presave()` to set the changed property of your node to what you want it to be. If it is "younger" than the one stored in cache it will not be displayed as "new" in the content list.

Answer (score 1):

You should "uncheck" the checkbox "promoted to the frontpage" (which is shown when you 'edit' such nodes). That way it will not be shown on the frontpage anymore.

Comment: Please refrain from adding extraneous comments to your answers like "let us know if that helps" and "If it does not help, then EDIT your question...", and also from asking follow up questions in answers. These are not part of your attempt to answer the question and as such don't belong in the answer. Please use comments to comment and gather more information about the problem, and only use answers to answer the question, remembering that this is Q+A, not a discussion forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the respective node those you want to remove the front page and uncheck the checkbox 'Promoted to the frontpage' and save it. This will remove your out dated content from the front page

Answer (score 1):

That "new"/"updated" label is drupal feature to show users that particular content is new / has changed since his last visit - its "per user", every user can see different content as new.

I would change your "content list" instead of this built-in behavior. I guess content list is view and you can add sorting / filter to that view with "Node: has new content" property.

Edit: but if you want to disable it, you can disable Tracker core module.